# No compilation error without d.ts files

Tags: typescript

I would like that the compilation of my TypeScript application fails if I don't have the typings (installed and references in TypeScript files) corresponding to external libraries I use. At the moment, compilation is successful without them.

Here is the content of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Here is the code that I would like to throw errors (the `toastr` variable isn't defined and only provided at runtime):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>Hello world</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    toastr.info('I am here for few seconds');
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this. Typescript was written to be a superset of JavaScript, so all valid JavaScript is valid Typescript. Valid JavaScript can be untyped, so valid Typescript can be untyped. The Typescript compiler could have this built in to it, but I'm not aware of any such feature. You could try a feature request https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: Is toastr referenced in a file somewhere in the tree? This doesn't compile for me so something must be different.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want use the toastr typings?

Comment: you need `noEmitOnError` to be `false`. That said I don't recommend it. See my answer 

Comment: @Sohnee really? I don't have compilation error on my side when running the tsc command... That said I have an error in Sublime with the Typescript plugin.

Comment: @rgvassar no I want to use it but if I forget, I would like to see some errors at the compilation level...

Comment: @basarat: I probably missed something but even with the `noEmitOnError` property set to false, I can't see the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default TypeScript will emit JavaScript even in the presence of errors. [This is a feature. See Why TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

That said you have in your tsconfig `"noEmitOnError": false,`. If you change it to true you will not get an emit if there is any error. Please note that this can decrease incremental compilation performance as the compiler needs to do whole program analysis even to give an emit on a single file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I asked this question because the build of Angular2 allows this. I mean when there is an error, the compilation failed and I was curious how to configure this within the typescript configuration file...

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/tools/broccoli/trees/browser_tree.ts#L169

Comment: I guess that it's because they don't use the same compiler ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to make the compiler shut up is to declare the **toastr** variable as any.

```
declare toastr: any;
```

Comment: Yes I know this ;-) In fact my question was: if I forget this, how to see a compilation error...