# Angular2 Cannot find module 'angular2/core' but application works

Tags: angular, typescript

Given I have app written in Angular2 with `app.component.ts` and some imports in it:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {FiltersService} from "./services/filters-service";
import {SearchPipe} from "./pipes/header-pipe";
import {PaginationPipe} from "./pipes/pagination-pipe";


import {Header} from "./components/header/header.component";
import {Pagination} from "./components/pagination/pagination.component";
import {ConfigService} from "./services/config-service";
import {ResourceService} from "./services/resource-service";
import {HttpService} from "./services/http-service";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {GlobalSearch} from "./components/global-search/global-search.component";
import {GlobalSearchPipe} from "./pipes/global-search-pipe";
import {CsvExport} from "./components/dropdown/csv-export.component";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
```

When I start app by `npm start`, the app is starting and works properly, but in the console I am getting:

```
app/app.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
app/app.component.ts(18,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there are two parts here:

- The **compilation part** that relies on typings (d.ts files). If these files can't be found for the definition of objects / classes used, you will have compilation error. This won't stop the compilation process. See this question for more details: [No compilation error without d.ts files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128753/no-compilation-error-without-d-ts-files).
- The **runtime part** that relies on JavaScript files. If corresponding files are included or available through the module manager, you will be able to use them.

In your case, I think that you can reach the `core.d.ts` file during compilation. When you configure your compiler with the value `node` for the `moduleResolution` property , it will (tsc) look for it within the `node_modules` folder.