# angular2 typescript not compiling, but works during runtime

Tags: typescript, angular

I am new to Angular2 typescript. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work during compile time, but if I change it during run-time, it works fine?

```
@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {
    history: String[] = [];

    addHistory(a: string) {
        this.history.push(a);
        return this.history;
    }
}
```

The compile time error it gives me is "error TS2322: Type 'String[]' is not assignable to type 'String'.
  Property 'charAt' is missing in type 'String[]'."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there are two parts in TypeScript applications. The compilation one and the execution one.

You need to recall that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. Your code can be valid regarding JavaScript but not regarding TypeScript (for example because of type checking). By default TypeScript will emit JavaScript even in the presence of errors.

That's the case here...

See this question for more details:

- [No compilation error without d.ts files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128753/no-compilation-error-without-d-ts-files)

Comment: I think you mean superset!

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is throwing the error? Am I declaring the string array incorrectly?