# How to write es 6 code with typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I work with asp.net project in visual studio 2015. I want to use typescript for transpile my code from es6 to es5. But some es6 features dont working in typescript. For example es6 classes don't working.

It is valid es6 code:

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(message) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

But this code generates the error '**property greeting does not exist on type Greeter**'. But transpiling working, i see valid es 5!

What i do wrong? Maybe linter error?

Comment: You haven't defined `greeting` so it is completely valid to give an error of it

Comment: if you want to write es6, write es6. If you want to write typescript, define the variable: ```class Greeter { greeting:string ; constr...```. You're getting valid output, because by default the compiler will emit even if there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `greeting` before using it like `this.greeting`.

Try this:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string; <-- you are missing this
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

By default TypeScript will emit JavaScript even in the presence of errors. You can turn off this by enabling `--noEmitOnError` compiler option. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816422/angular2-typescript-not-compiling-but-works-during-runtime)

Read official docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) for better understanding.

Compiler options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)