# Angular 2 - Pass parameters to service

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I pass a string (which will be a url) to a service? Since my 'service' is always going to be an http get request, it makes sense to keep it generic as possible and make the controller pass the url through to it instead of making dozens of separate controllers with different urls in them.

So far my controller looks like this:

```
this._httpService.getOffers()
            .subscribe(
            data => { this.offers = <Offer[]>data.offers; },
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("Finished")
        );
```

and in my 'service' it looks like this:

```
getOffers() {
            return this._http.get('json/test.json')
                .map(res => res.json())
        }
```

But I want to move "json/test.json" to the controller.

Comment: Just pass a parameter to getOffers function `getOffers(url: string)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this this way:

```
getOffers(url:string) { // <----
  return this._http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

and call it like this:

```
this._httpService.getOffers('json/test.json')
        .subscribe(
        data => { this.offers = <Offer[]>data.offers; },
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log("Finished")
    );
```

Comment: Do I have to say 'url:string' in the service? Couldn't I just use 'url'?

Comment: Yes, you can since TypeScript is a superset of JS. Everything you can do in JS can be done in TS. That being said, leveraging type checking could be interesting ;-)

Comment: Ah thanks. I've always wondered because it allows me to just say 'url' all fine. Is there a way I can compile the code that would bring that error up to notify me that I missed it out?

Comment: You're welcmome! In fact no but if you have compilation `tsc` (typescript compiler) will tell you. This question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128753/no-compilation-error-without-d-ts-files

Comment: Ah yes I have a compiler but didn't notice the error messages in there. There's only 1 error which I'm sure I can resolve. Thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    this._httpService.getOffers(url:string)
                .subscribe(
                data => { this.offers = <Offer[]>data.offers; },
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log("Finished")
            );


getOffers(url:string) {
            return this._http.get(url)
                .map(res => res.json())
        }
```